# get back on/to her feet

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> She runs into the stairwell, loses her footing and tumbles down the stairs. She recovers, **gets back on/to her feet** and continues down the stairs.

Are both "on" and "to" correct here? Is there any difference between them? Are they equally natural?

Comment: Get back on your feet generally refers to recovering from illness (and financial or economic woes).  I would use get back to her feet in this case.

Answer (score 1):

"Onto" and "on" can be used interchangeably with many verbs, *e.g.*, "set," "put," and "place." "Gets" is one such verb. "To" and "in" do not have frequent occurrences where they can be used interchangeably, but "gets to her feet," "gets on her feet," and "gets onto her feet" all are acceptable.

This may be a personal quirk, but I would use "gets to her feet" if and only if I meant to imply some degree of difficulty in doing so.

**EDIT**: There may be differences between American and British English. "On" is far more common than "to" in this context in American English. See

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gets+back+on+his+feet%2Cgets+back+to+his+feet&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgets%20back%20on%20his%20feet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgets%20back%20to%20his%20feet%3B%2Cc0